# Js file load order in meteor

Tags: meteor

In meteor docs it is written that all files in project_root/lib folder are loaded first;

I have this code:

```
//defined in /lib/utilties.js
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    return this.replace(/(^|\s)([a-z])/g, function(m, p1, p2) { 
        return p1 + p2.toUpperCase();
    });
};
```

and this:

```
//defined in /client/event-helpers/form.js
Template.form.helpers({
    fieldType: function(field) {
        return 'form-' + capitalize(field)
    }
});
```

this doesn't work saying that capitalize is undefined; moving capitalize function in /client/event-helpers/form.js let it work;
So can someone help me to understand the file load priority in meteor and why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have interpreted the documentation correctly with respect to load order, but that isn't the issue with your code. You added `capitalize` to the `String` prototype, but you are using it like a global function. Try this instead:

```js
return 'form-' + field.capitalize();
```

Comment: Sure the load order has been interpreted correctly ("all files in project_root/lib folder are loaded first")? I interpret it as that too, but a small test app I just created loads `client/lib/test.js` before `lib/test.js`. A bug?

Comment: He's correct in that lib folders get loaded first, however nested folders also have elevated priority. So I'm pretty sure a nested AND lib folder will be loaded before anything else, which explains your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misinterpreted the documents. Files in the lib directory are not loaded first. Files in the lowest subdirectories are loaded first.

Comment: well "After sorting as described above, all files under directories named lib are moved before everything else, preserving their order." - this is written in official docs; common code for client and server should be loaded first;

Comment: But if you look at the example they use a client/lib directory for stuff that should be explicitly loaded on the client first.

Comment: so, where do should be placed common functions that can be used from client and server and that needs to be loaded as the first thing?

Comment: I still have the same error also moving capitalize function in /client/lib/main/utilities.js

Comment: @CerealKiller, I usually use a directory named `both` for files that should be loaded before everything else on both the client and the server.